# Why I have different results for python and java base64 encode for the same text?

Tags: java, python, base64

I have two codes in python and java as following, but run them to different results, what happened?

python2.7 code：

```py
#encoding:utf-8
import json
import base64

st_test = {"test":"测试内容"}
body = json.dumps(st_test,ensure_ascii=False)
res = base64.b64encode(body)
prin res 
#eyJ0ZXN0IjogIua1i+ivleWGheWuuSJ9
```

Java code:

```java
import java.util.Base64;

body = "{\"test\":\"测试内容\"}";
String body64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(body.getBytes("UTF-8")) ;
System.out.println(body64);
//eyJ0ZXN0Ijoi5rWL6K+V5YaF5a65In0=
```

Comment: I'd start by looking at `json.dumps(st_test,ensure_ascii=False)` and `body.getBytes("UTF-8")`. Are they identical? If not, why would you expect their base64 encodings to be identical?

Comment: `eyJ0ZXN0IjogIua1i+ivleWGheWuuSJ9` is being decoded as `{"test":"测试内容"}` while `eyJ0ZXN0Ijoi5rWL6K+V5YaF5a65In0=` is being decoded as `{"test": "测试内容"}`

Comment: In Python 2 you have mark Unicode strings with a `u`: `{"test": u"测试内容"}`. BTW it might be a good time to upgrade to Python 3.

Comment: Also, there's a space after the colon  in the java one and not in python.

Comment: How do you know they are identical? You should store the string in a file and read it off the disk then compare again.

Comment: first you should display and compare values in `body`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two different strings - `Java` doesn't have space after `:`

If I remove space

```
body = body.replace(' ', '')
```

then I get the same code

---

```
import json
import base64

st_test = {"test": "测试内容"}
body = json.dumps(st_test, ensure_ascii=False)
print body

body = body.replace(' ', '')
print body

res = base64.b64encode(body)
print res
print (res == 'eyJ0ZXN0Ijoi5rWL6K+V5YaF5a65In0=')
```

Result

```
{"test": "测试内容"}
{"test":"测试内容"}
eyJ0ZXN0Ijoi5rWL6K+V5YaF5a65In0=
True
```

Comment: ```body=json.dumps(st_test, ensure_ascii=False, separators=(',',':'))``` I found it also worked and 'separators' option compact encoding.

Comment: I didn't know `separatotors`. I checked it compacts also with `separators=',:'`